Error on mysql when running from a jenkinsfile on a docker image
I am running a WSL on my Windows11. On top of that I have a Jenkins container with a Docker-in-Docker image, so when I am running my tests through the Jenkinsfile I can create a container with the required software, for example, node:14 or mysql:8. But I am running into errors when working with a MySQL image.
When testing this setup I created the following Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Checkout code from github') {
            agent any
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/OzMashiah/learningjenkins.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Run JavaScript') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:14'
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'ls -l'
                    sh 'node script.js'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run MySQL Query') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'mysql:8'
                }
            }
            environment {
                MYSQL_USER = 'root'
                MYSQL_DB = 'test_db'
                MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD = true
            }
            steps {
                script {
                // Ensure MySQL is initialized before running commands
                        sh 'sleep 15'
                        sh '/usr/sbin/mysqld status'

                        sh '''
                                mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DB};"
                                mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} ${MYSQL_DB} -e "
                                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                                                id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                                                name VARCHAR(50)
                                        );
                                        INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John Doe');
                                        INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Jane Doe');
                                        "
                        '''
                        sh """
                                mysql -u ${MYSQL_USER} ${MYSQL_DB} -e "SELECT * FROM users;"
                        """
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            // Clean up resources after the build
            echo 'Cleaning up resources...'
        }
    }
}

The JavaScript  stage works well but running into errors on the mysql stage.
This is the error I get when trying to run the mysql command:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

which looks like the mysqld is not running, therefore I try to get the status and get the following:
+ /usr/sbin/mysqld status

2024-12-12T10:12:15.290153Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.564828Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.3) starting as process 46

2024-12-12T10:12:15.600460Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 8fd96474-b871-11ef-a35e-0242ac110002.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.621615Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.639907Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.639958Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.639972Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.

2024-12-12T10:12:15.639980Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation

2024-12-12T10:12:15.640283Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.

script returned exit code 3

I would like to note that when I am running a simple docker container outside of jenkins of a mysql:8 image and connect via docker exec /bin/bash I manage to run mysql smoothly.

I'm pretty sure, when Jenkins runs a container as an agent, it overrides a lot of things so that the normal main container process isn't running.  Jenkins has a standard way to run containers during a build and that may work better here.  You also might consider adopting a standard database-migration system so that your developers can set up this environment separately from the CI system.

Thanks for the answer @DavidMaze. I tried implementing it as a sidecar container, such as : script {
node {
docker.image('mysql:8').withRun('-p 3306:3306 ) { c ->
sh "docker exec ${c.id} bash -c 'mysql -e "SELECT 1"'"
}
}
}
But the error is still: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

You shouldn't need docker exec to interact with the database.  In the Jenkins setup you need to do a little bit of manual setup to sh 'docker network create' a network, but then the migrations bundled with your application can talk to the container database the same way they would any other (remote) database.
